# Best test to assess statistical difference between two groups on a set of 5-point questionnaire items

Tags: survey, ordinal-data, likert, group-differences

I have a set of data which contains answers to a questionnaire (questions about satisfaction rated 1 to 5) and some demographic information (sex, age). I can divide the data in two groups and I want to see if there is any statistical difference between those groups. I tried the Wilcoxon test, but I have many ties, so I'm not sure this is the test that I need. What would be the best test in this case?

Comment: Are you saying that the response scale for each item is 1 to 5? Or are you saying that respondents rank five questions 1 to 5? Or did you form an overall scale scores by taking the mean or sum of items? How are the two groups formed?

Comment: Yes, the response scale is 1 to 5 (how satisfied a patient was with different aspects of his/her admission to a hospital).

Comment: As a somehow related question - if you jiggle the results so there are no ties (i.e. instead of 1, 1, 2, 2 you use 1.01, 1.02, 2.01, 2.02) would Wilcoxon test be applicable to show a significant difference between the two groups? I have about 300-400 patients that answered the questions.

Comment: So participants are not "ranking", they are "rating"? How many items do you have? Are you combining these items into a composite score? or if not how are you dealing with multiple items?

Comment: Yes, they are rating. I want to check the differences for each question separately, not a composite score. So for the purpose of my question you can assume there is only one set of answers

Comment: Is your question any different from this one? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203/group-differences-on-a-five-point-likert-item

Comment: @Jeromy - looks like it's the same question, however I don't know the terms, so I didn't find it in my search. What did you end up using in the end? Do you think t-test would be good for my purpose?

Comment: There are at least five questions on how to compare two groups or two ordinal variables: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35382/5739, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49318/5739, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/203/5739, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59625/5739, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43113/5739, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56949/5739. So this is one of the most FAQed things on the site.

Answer (score -2):

two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Comment: The two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov does not deal with ties. If you ignore heavy ties you end up with a much lower significance level than desired, with corresponding impact on power. You would need to explain how to deal with ties.

Comment: I'm interested in the issue with the ties, since by design there are going to be plenty of ties. There are 300-400 respondents and there are 5 answers to choose from.

Comment: K-S test only works for continuous data, assuming that your CDF does not have jumps that mess up the asymptotic distribution.